# Accessing java applets public variables

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I sent values to the signed applet.

On html:

```
    <applet 
            id='appletid' 
            codebase="/demo/" 
            code='appletpkg.appletclass' 
            archive='./sapplet.jar' 
            width=1 height=1>
       <param name="valuename1" value="value1">
    </applet>
```

In the applet public class:

```
public String[] str = new String[100];

@Override
public void init() {

    nstr = this.getParameter("valuename1");
    //TODO
    this.str[0]= "appletstringvalue1";

}
```

At javascript:

```
 var a = document.getElementById('appletid');
 var jstr = a.str;

 alert('jstr: '+jstr[0]);
```

If I use a similar script with ORACLE JRE on windows or mac the alerts shows a string.

```
jstr: appletstringvalue1
```

But if I use similiar script on ubuntu with OPENJDK I receive.

```
jstr: undefined
```

The java.log shows the value of jstr if I print to the log in both cases.

Why Javascript is not receiving the applet values on linux or openjdk?

Any suggestion?

Thank You.

Comment: Be sure to add `<param name="scriptable" value="true" >` or rather, the equivalent using the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).

Comment: Adding this parameter is not a solution.